# Append text to a file every minute using crontab in mac os x is not working

Tags: macos, cron

I'm trying to run a cron command every minute in mac os. Below is the code for my `.sh` file named `logit.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/Users/myname/Desktop

printf "\nThis is a new line to your document" >> file.txt
```

I made the file executable with below command

```
sudo chmod +x /Users/myname/Desktop/logit.sh
```

Below is the code for my crontab. I need to run the command every minute to append the text to the text file to check whether cron is working properly.

```
 * * * * * sh /Users/myname/Desktop/logit.sh
```

I tried the below command as well, it doesn't work

```
* * * * * /Users/myname/Desktop/logit.sh
```

However, if I give the below command in the terminal, it works fine.

```
sh /Users/myname/Desktop/logit.sh
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Who owns the file file.txt .   Just making sure it's the same user as the crontab.  Also does whereis sh tell you where your osx sh is? per this doc you might have to add the proper Path https://askubuntu.com/questions/350861/how-to-set-a-cron-job-to-run-a-shell-script

Comment: @Cameron same user

Comment: may need full server path from cron.   
* * * * * /yourfullpatchto/Users/myname/Desktop/logit.sh

what does a pwd give you from the Desktop folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the syntax for the crontab file. Below is the code which worked for me.

```
* * * * * cd /Users/myname/Desktop && ./logit.sh
```